# Creating a woocommerce store that gets products from another website

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am in need of guidance:

I need to create a woocommerce store that will get its products from another website like [this one](http://www.varuna.ro/). Is it possible to make it to auto update? For example, every time a product is introduced into the first store, the same product will appear in my woocommerce store?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: A lot depends on the other site. Is it in your control? Is it running WooCommerce? Do you have the right to re post their products?

Comment: No it is not woocommerce. And about the rights I am not sure.

Comment: I have the right to post the product.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using file_get_contents() to read the other website then you can parse the pages you receive to select the products and display your own page on the fly.